# Spring Security Annotation Configuration not doing anything

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem setting Spring Security up.
So to start with, I have a Configuration class, something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.boardviewer")
public class BoardviewerConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private BoardviewerSecurityService boardviewerSecurityService;

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean /* The "${props} can now be parsed before runtime with this bean declaration */
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    /* Spring Sec */

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider dao = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        dao.setUserDetailsService(boardviewerSecurityService);
        return dao;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderManager providerManager() {
        List<AuthenticationProvider> list = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
        list.add(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        return new ProviderManager(list);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.userDetailsService(boardviewerSecurityService);
    }    
}
```

Basically some basic WebSecurity configs...
I'm not getting ANY errors, but I can browse around the site normally without any restrictions.

For instance, I have a controller with the @PreAuthorize annotation, and I get straight through it.

I'm running Spring Security 3.2.0 RC2 to be able to get an annotation configuration going... But so far no luck.

Is there any additional config in the web.xml needed? Or am I missing something?
Anyone got an example of a working Spring Security annotation config?

Also, I'm using hibernate to fetch User accounts etc, and my `boardviewerSecurityService` looks like this:

```
@Service
public class BoardviewerSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Inject
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Inject
    private BoardviewerTransformer transformer;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User u = userDAO.getByUsername(s);
        if(u == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Couldn't find a user with that username");
        } else {
            return transformer.userToSpringUser(u);
        }
    }
}
```

And the transformer simply remaps the entity to a Spring UserDetails `User` object (`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`)

Am I missing something? (A part from setting up the login page and url interceptors? I thought I won't need those since I only want to control access on class / method level)

Would appreciate any help!

Regards

Comment: The security only works in the same application context as the beans are defined in. Move/or add the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` to the configuration which is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: @M.Deinum But this is my only configuration file. Except for the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` config file. But that contains almost only annotation-driven attributes. I pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/WSVsBHfE
All my beans are in the first Configuration class, which i posted up top of the OP. Do I need to add something to tell Spring Security that it should be annotation driven?

Comment: The problem is security is applied through AOP and AOP works with `Bean(Factory)PostProcessors`. Those operate only on beans in the **SAME** application context. My guess is that this configuration class is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and not the `DispatcherServlet`. Add `<sec:global-method-security />` tag to your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml. Or create an `@Configuration` class put the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
` on it and place that class in the configuration of the `DispatcherServlet`

Comment: @M.Deinum What do you mean by the line "and place that class in the configuration of the DispatcherServlet" ? Like declaring it with a <context-param> ?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have a component-scan in my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` shouldn't that find all the `@Configuration` files? It's still not working tho.

Comment: If that is your configuration you are having another problem (also) bean duplication. Post your web.xml...

Comment: Also you only have the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` but haven't enabled anything. Add `prePostEnabled=true` to your annotation. As you have the annotation on a controller method you probably have to add `proxyTargetClass=true` also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42133/discussion-between-robin-jonsson-and-m-deinum)